# Unique combination of values

Tags: sqlite, unique-constraint

I want to create a database for my program. Most likely I will use SQLite, although others are an option.

I will have columns `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`. `a` is unique and will be my primary key. `b`, `c`, `d` are allowed to contain duplicate value.

However, I don't want *combinations* of `b`, `c`, `d` to repeat. For instance, sample valid db:

```
a   b   c   d
0   18  n   kiwi
1   12  v   kiwi
2   15  t   orange
3   12  j   kiwi
4   12  t   banana
5   31  f   apple
6   10  h   kiwi
7   15  y   orange
8   20  b   apple
9   1   m   grapefruit
10  7   s   apple
11  4   h   banana
12  31  t   egg
```

Sample invalid db (rows `2` and `7`):

```
a   b   c   d
0   18  n   kiwi
1   12  v   kiwi
2   15  y   orange
3   12  j   kiwi
4   12  t   banana
5   31  f   apple
6   10  h   kiwi
7   15  y   orange
8   20  b   apple
9   1   m   grapefruit
10  7   s   apple
11  4   h   banana
12  31  t   egg
```

Is there standard database rule or concept that applies to this?

I can of course simply do validation in my code, by manually querying the db. I believe I could also construct a fifth `bcd` column, which concatenates the other three, and is required to be unique. But both of these seem hacky. Is it possible to somehow "declare the columns unique in combination only" in a more direct and obvious way?

For instance, I could declare `(b, c, d)` as my composite primary key (not sure if SQLite supports this but I think SQL does). That should accomplish my goal. However, I don't want these columns to actually be my PK.

Comment: You need a `UNIQUE` constraint/index on `(b,c,d)`. In SQLite there's no difference between a PRIMARY KEY and a UNIQUE constraint/index on NOT NULL columns. (except that you can have many UNIQUE ones but only one PRIMARY KEY). See: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: (and the exception about single-column integer primary keys that have some special properties).

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX your_unique_index ON your_table(b, c, d);
```

Create an index instead. It has the same as the unique constraint.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the OP create a unique index *instead of a unique constraint*? If so, why?